# Writing to a file share on AWS EC2 instance using .net core that runs in a Fargate linux container

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core

I'm new to AWS cloud services. I have a new application that is written in .net core. The application is deployed using a fargate linux container.  I want to write to a file share that is on EC2 instance. In the startup of the application, I'm assuming I have to load a service from aws. However, I'm not for sure what service will mount the file share directory.  Any suggestions about how to add the fileshare to startup.cs ?

Comment: EFS is AWS's NFS service.

Comment: Is this service the only way to connect to the fileshare on a ec2 instance to a fargate container?

Comment: A fileshare, yes, but there are many other options for services to share communicate or share data other than a fileshare

Comment: If I want to create a file using a StreamWriter in .net core then  save it to a s3bucket in aws. Is this possible?